# Create Result Source with PowerShell?

Tags: search, result-source

Is it possible to do something like in this [tutorial](http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2014/10/01/article-customizing-sharepoint-2013-results-using-result-sources/) programmatically or in powershell?

1. Create result source with some custom search query
2. Create new page
3. Add search result webpart to page in step 2, and configure it, it needs to use the result source created in step 1
4. Extend the search center page with my custom result source. Like: Everything, people, conversation, videos and myCustomResultSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create result source with some custom search query

   - [Create Result Source with PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/searchguys/archive/2013/06/14/creating-result-sources-using-powershell.aspx)
2. Create new page

   - [How to create a page in powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4851550d-25e4-452f-8542-9faf2c63c3c7/how-to-create-a-page-in-powershell)
3. Add search result webpart to page in step 2, and configure it, it
   needs to use the result source created in step 1

   - [Adding Web part on pages using PowerShell script](http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.in/2012/11/adding-web-part-on-pages-using.html)
   - Important note: In 99.9% of the cases, you'd have to pre-config the webpart and export it to insert it on a page via Powershell.
4. Configure the page created in step 2

   - Configure the page how?

Comment: step 4 is to extend the search center page with my custom result source. Like: Everything, people, conversation, videos and myCustomResultSource.

Comment: @KHA Corrected the link to "Create Result Source with PowerShell"

Comment: @DanielZiga : Can we create result source using PowerShell CSOM? I would like to create result source in Office365 sharePoint site.

Comment: @AsadRefai I honestly don't know. I haven't been in a situation where I needed to do it through CSOM. Sorry.